# Scrollview.js no 'pageChange' event on scroll back

Tags: famo.us

Scrollview.js does not trigger goToPreviousPage which means there is no pageChange event happening on scrolling back. Is this an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug, there is already a pull request with a fix to this. Created an issue which has a reference to the needed change, as a work around forked the repo and made the change locally

https://github.com/Famous/famous/issues/205

Answer (score 3):

No it's not. Scrollview has a number of really annoying bugs. Some of which are only a problem when not on mobile. Pagination for instance works better when run on mobile / through cordova. Two weeks ago they said they where going to release a new version soon so hopefully maybe we'll have a new Scrollview soon.

In the mean time what are you trying to do. Maybe I can help with a work around. I do have a side to side "paginated scrollview" that works well. It basically populates either side of the screen and lets you slide it into view then repopulates the sides. https://github.com/vizidrix/famous/blob/master/page-swaper/PageSwaper.js

```
 pass it 
    height:
    width: 
    data: [], // the array of items like any scrollview.
    selected: 0, // the index you want to start on.
```

it will emit this._eventOutput.emit('show', { item: this.options.data[this.options.selected] });
on change so you will always know what your selected on.

Heres hoping we get a new Scrollview soon.

Comment: Thanks, will look into PageSwapper and famo.us git repo for issues

Comment: The new version of scroll view should be released soon, possibly in just a couple days if they release as their Aug 13, 2014 event.